# Classification of Moufang planes of real dimension 16

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, incidence-geometry, octonions

Incidence geometry is not really area of expertise so I'm asking here: are all **Moufang planes of 16 dimension** already classified?
I'm not just interested in the compact ones. Is there already a classification that consider for example $\mathbb{P}^{2}\left(O_s\right)$?

Looking on internet I found some work of Salzmann which was not really easy to read and  seems to involve knowing the dimension of the collineation group.

If someone from the incidence geometry community could give me some hint, reference or update on the state of the art it would be very much appreciated.